# Cabinet Latch like a Door Knob

Tags: cabinets, doorknob

I am trying to build a custom cabinet with a trash drawer that is dog proof.   I don't like the two-handed operation of the baby latches, so I was thinking something like a door knob.   I would want it to work just like a door knob except no knob on the inside and a thinner latching mechanism so I don't have to build my cabinet door 1.5" thick.

Since I am building it myself, I could just build out the frame where the latch is going to be to 1.5" and then modify the knob hardware to eliminate the inside knob.

Open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a surface-mounted cabinet twist latch:

[image]
<sup>image courtesy of houseofantiquehardware.com</sup>

Or, if your pup likes to open latches by biting, use a recessed slam latch:

[image]
<sup>image courtesy of actronmfginc.com</sup>

also called [paddle-handle push-to-close latch](https://www.mcmaster.com/slam-latches/paddle-handle-push-to-close-latches/), to protect her or his teeth?

Of course, if the bin is large enough to trap a person, you **do need** an inside handle!

Comment: +1 for thinking about my 3 y.o. Grandson.

Comment: The paddle latch is perfect.

Comment: Thanks to @FreeMan for the edit.